# Convert a JsValue to a model via Reads[T] which consists of a list of tuples

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have the following class:

```
case class Model(elements: List[(String, String)])
```

Now I want to fill my model `Model` with the values of a `JsValue` by using `Reads[T]`. The JSON could have different key values pairs which are unknown at the time of unmarshaling them and therefore I want to have them as a list of tuples.

For example:

```
{ "foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}
```

Should become:

```
List(("foo" -> "bar"), ("barfoo" -> "foobar"))
```

The problem is that I don't know how I can achieve a sort of wildcard function that matches all elements in a JSON object, but not nested ones or arrays.

```
implicit val modelReads: Reads[Model] = (
        (JsPath \ "?").read[String] // and
     // (JsPath \ "foo").read[String] // and <- key not known in advance
     // (JsPath \ "barfoo").read[String] // <- key not known in advance
        ) (Model.apply _)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to use Play JSON combinators for everything here, as they only work with fixed field mappings. For you to be able to read the `elements` field, you would need to implement a `Reads[List[(String, String)]]`. Fortunately, Play already has a `Reads[Map[A, B]]` available (for types `A` and `B` that also have a `Reads`), and a `Map[A, B]` can easily be converted into a `List[(A, B)]` (underneath a `Map` is just a collection of tuples).

For a one-off case, we can use `read[Map[String, String]]` and `map` it to a `List`. Then, we can map that to the case class. Assuming the following JSON structure:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{"element": { "foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}}""")
```

You can write:

```
implicit val reads = (__ \ "elements").read[Map[String, String]]
  .map(_.toList)
  .map(tuples => Model(tuples))
```

And try it out:

```
scala> js.validate[Model]
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Model] = JsSuccess(Model(List((foo,bar), (barfoo,foobar))),/elements)
```

Note that the `Reads[Model]` above is kind of a special case, because the case class only had a single field. To take this a bit further and see how it can play with JSON combinators, let's add a new field:

```
case class Model(elements: List[(String, String)], info: String)
```

Then, let's also make our `Reads` for the tuples a little more generic, so that it can handle values of any type `A` where a `Reads[A]` is available:

```
implicit def tupleReads[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): Reads[List[(String, A)]] =
  Reads.mapReads(rds).map(_.toList)
```

Now we can write a `Reads` using combinators for the newly defined `Model`, the same as you're used to:

```
implicit val reads = (
  (__ \ "elements").read[List[(String, String)]] and
  (__ \ "info").read[String]
)(Model.apply _)
```

Trying it out:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{"elements": { "foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}, "info": "test"}""")

scala> js.validate[Model]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Model] = JsSuccess(Model(List((foo,bar), (barfoo,foobar)),test),)
```

If your JSON structure *only* looks like `{"foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}` (without an `elements` key), then we can still leverage the same generic `Reads[List[(String, A)]]`, but will need to implement a more custom `Reads[Model]` to map an entire object to one model field. Let's we want to map the above JSON to:

```
Model(List(("foo" -> "bar"), ("barfoo" -> "foobar")))
```

The `Reads[Model]` we need will basically be the same as the first one I defined, except that we can drop the `JsPath` from it:

```
// Use `tupleReads` as defined above, restricted to `String`
implicit val reads = tupleReads[String].map(tuples => Model(tuples))
```

It works:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{"foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}""")

scala> js.validate[Model]
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Model] = JsSuccess(Model(List((foo,bar), (barfoo,foobar))),)
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you very much Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the draft code:

```
val json = Json.parse("""
  { "foo": "bar", "barfoo": "foobar"}
""")

implicit val readMetaTag = 
  Reads(js => JsSuccess(
      Model(js.as[JsObject].fieldSet.map(
          tag => (tag._1, tag._2.as[String])).toList)))

val model = json.as[Model]

println("Model: " + model)
//Model: Model(List((foo,bar), (barfoo,foobar)))
```

Comment: It isn't safe to use `as` when defining a `Reads`. If you try to `validate` something that isn't a `JsObject`, it will throw an exception, which is _not_ something you should expect when using a supposedly safe method. `val json = JsNumber(1) ; json.validate[Model]`

Comment: yea, your answer, @MichaelZajac is brilliant, thx for that as well