# Convert JsValue to a model via Reads[T] which consits parts of list of arbitrary tuples and parts of known objects

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

This question is similar to [Convert a JsValue to a model via Reads[T] which consists of a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753388/convert-a-jsvalue-to-a-model-via-readst-which-consists-of-a-list-of-tuples) which I asked couple of weeks ago.

So my API returns the following data:

```
{"firstName": "John", "age": "30", "ssn": "12345"}
```

Parts of this result (for example `firstName`) are known in advance, but most of the data is not known when converting the `JsValue` (in this example `age` and `ssn`).

The attributes which are not known, should be converted to a list of tuples.

I already have a working solution for a `Reads` that transforms the JSON to a model which consists of a list of tuples. However, I don't know how I can exclude the elements from the `tupleReads` which are known in advance.

For example:

```
case class Model(firstName: String, elements: List[(String, String)])

implicit def tupleReads[A](implicit rds: Reads[A]): Reads[List[(String, A)]] = Reads.mapReads(rds).map(_.toList)

implicit val elementsReads: Reads[Model] = tupleReads[String].map(tuples => Model(firstName = ??, elements = tuples)) // ??

val result = json.validate[Model]
```

Comment: are all your fields (including the known ones) of the same type (`String`, in your example)?

Comment: All of the fields do not necessarily share the same type, but they will be in most cases `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that differently, but first saying the fields will be `String` in most cases seems shaky, or do you really expect code which works only in most cases?

Therefore, I adapted your model:

```
case class Model(firstName: String, elements: List[(String, JsValue)])
```

And the reads:

```
val modelReads: Reads[Model] =
  ((__ \ 'firstName).read[String] and
    __.read(Reads.mapReads[JsValue].map(_.toList)))(Model)
```

which works as shown below:

```
scala> Json.parse("""{"firstName": "John", "age": "30", "ssn": "12345"}""")
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"firstName":"John","age":"30","ssn":"12345"}

scala> res0.validate[Model](modelReads)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Model] = JsSuccess(Model(John,List((firstName,"John"), (age,"30"), (ssn,"12345"))),)
```